# Vulkan-basic-samples fails to build in Android Studio 3.4.1 and grable 5.1.1

Tags: android

Vulkan-basic-samples fails to build in Android Studio 3.4.1 and grable 5.1.1

Error:
ERROR: The project name 'API-Samples/android/' must not contain any of the following characters: [/, \, :, <, >, ", ?, *, |]. Set the 'rootProject.name' or adjust the 'include' statement (see https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings:include(java.lang.String[]) for more details).

I've made changes, but it does not work.
Can someone help me solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the recent post
[Compiling Android Studio Vulkan Samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55772508/compiling-android-studio-vulkan-samples)
the problem was caused by updating the Android Gradle Plugin to the latest version.

When this update is cancelled, the samples built just fine for the poster.